# How to stop TextInput losing focus onChangeText?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, textinput

I want to change the state of a parent component from a child's TextInput.

The problem is every time it changes the parent state the component re-renders, the TextInput is blurred and the keyboard disappears.

I tried keeping all the logic in the some component and changing the parent state without passing props.  Now I've tried extracting the InputText container and putting it into a new file, changing the parents' state and receiving the value through the props, that's not working either.

Here is the text field component:

```
export default (ProfileTextInput = ({
  placeholder,
  label,
  handleChange,
  name,
  value
}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.inputComponent}>
      <Text style={styles.labelText}>{label.toUpperCase()}</Text>
      <TextInput
        key={Math.random()}
        placeholder={placeholder || ""}
        value={value}
        onChangeText={val => handleChange(val, name)}
      />
    </View>
  );
});
```

and this is how it's being used:

```
  const [newUserData, setNewUserData] = useState({ ...userData });

  const changeHandler = (value, name) => {
    setNewUserData({ ...newUserData, [name]: value });
  };


  return(
    <ProfileTextInput
      label="Username"
      defaultValue={newUserData.username}
      name="username"
      value={newUserData.username}
      handleChange={changeHandler}
    />
  )
```

I expected it to continue letting me type like a normal TextInput, but it's only typing one letter and losing focus.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `defaultValue` props from your components.

`defaultValue` is just the initial value passed to an uncontrolled component. Since you're setting the input value with a change handler, that makes your input a controlled component, and so you should just set the value explicitly.

Read these articles for more details on the differences between these cases:

- [React forms and controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)
- [Uncontrolled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

Comment: I've tried it and I'm still having the same problem.  Every time I type and change the state of the parent using ```onChangeText``` it re-renders and removes the keyboard.